# is it possible to create array with same key in php?

Tags: php

i'm having problem with sendin soap request using php,xml code looks like below:
**

```
<list> 
  <ExtIdList>
   <serviceExtId set="true">
   <value>$value1</value>
  </serviceExtId>
  <ExtIdType set="true">
   <value>1</value>
  </ExtIdType>
  </ExtIdList>

  <ExtIdList>
   <serviceExtId set="true">
   <value>$value2</value>
  </serviceExtId>
  <ExtIdType set="true">
   <value>2</value>
  </ExtIdType>
  </ExtIdList>
 </list>
```

**

the problem is here i can't translate it to array, if translate it to array here will be 2 same keys. is there any way to send such soap request using php?

Comment: Which node will be the key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I'm not sure it applies to your situation, but it worked for me when I was sending to XERO api multiple phones) - something like nested arrays:

```
$phones =
array(
    array(
        'Phone' => array(
            'PhoneType' => 'DEFAULT',
            'PhoneNumber' => $values['phone']
    )),
    array(
        'Phone' => array(
            'PhoneType' => 'MOBILE',
            'PhoneNumber' => $values['mobile']
    ))
);
```

In your case replace `'Phone'` key with `'ExtIdList'`

Comment: thanks for response but it didn't work for me. when i checked logs in our server this part simply was missing in the request.